# jQuery function that check empty input tags in PHP, AJAX Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I did research but end up stuck with my PHP AJAX Form. My form is working already but I want to add some user experience like change border to red when HTML input tag is empty or criteria didn't match.

This is my PHP, AJAX form works. I validated users input in server side via PHP, not client side then return errors if any in JSON format to my jQuery/Javascript code. I want to know which HTML input tags are empty or failed so I can add a class of those input tags.

This is my return JSON from PHP and I converted to JSON.parse n jQuery/Javascript code.

```
{
    "errors": [{
        "firstname": "Missing First name"
    }, {
        "lastname": "Missing Last name"
    }]
}
```

I checked response if there's error here my JS code

```
var json = JSON.parse(response);
if (json.hasOwnProperty('errors') && json.errors.length > 0) {
     // I want to call a function here that detect which input tags are empty then add a class.                
   }else {
       //execute other function
  }
```

PHP code

```
<?php

$firstname = isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : null;
$lastname = isset($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : null;

$errors = []; //array for errors
$noError = "No error found";
if(empty($_POST['firstname'])){
    $errors[]['firstname'] = 'Missing First name';
}else{
    $firstname = sanitizedData($_POST['firstname']);
}
if (empty($_POST['lastname'])) {
    $errors[]['lastname'] = 'Missing Last name';
}else{
    $lastname = sanitizedData($_POST['lastname']);
}


if(!empty($errors)){
    $result_array = array('errors' => $errors);
    echo json_encode($result_array);
    exit();
}else{
    echo json_encode($noError);   
}

//sanitized data from user inputs
function sanitizedData($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

?>
```

Comment: What is problem with the code?

Comment: Hi @Eddie, nothing wrong with my code, instead I need some help to detect if input tags are empty or validation failed.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to call a function here that detect which input tags are empty
>   then add a class.

Add a common class to all the input that need to be validated. Inside the `if` statement call a `function`

Use document.querySelectorAll to get all the input element which need to be validate.Use `forEach` to iterate and check if it is empty. Then use `classList.add` to add an error class in it

```js
function checkInput() {
  var getAllInput = document.querySelectorAll('.ipClass');
  getAllInput.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.value === '') {
      item.classList.add('error')
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="ipClass">
<input type="text" class="ipClass">
<input type="text" class="ipClass">
<input type="text" class="ipClass">
<button onclick="checkInput()">Check</button>
```

Comment: Hi @brk, can you please explain why you use forEach not for loops?

Comment: @darkRabbit forEach is an in build array method,& to me it is more concise & cleaner than for-loop, You can also use for loop if you wish

Comment: I see, before asking here I have this code     for(i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
          var input = inputs[i];
          if(errors.indexOf(input.name) >= 0) {
            input.classList.add('error');
          }
        } but nothing happen